# This cardinal exist in ZFC

Tags: set-theory

Does $2^{{\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0}}$ exist in ZFC without additional large cardinals axioms?

Comment: Is it $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$ or $2^{\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}}$? The answer is actually yes in both cases, but these aren't the same cardinal. (They are also both rather "small" by ZFC standards.)

Comment: Both $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ and $2^{(\aleph_0^{\aleph_0})}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ exist in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware than exponentiation have priority by the right, like in real numbers, is it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, you don't need any additional axioms. Specifically, it is a good exercise to show that ZFC proves that, for any sets $A$ and $B$, the set of maps from $A$ to $B$ exists.